# Validate array against mongodb collection array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, validation

I am trying to validate against my mongodb collection. We have events stored as an array within the collection.

collection information: `[New York, Palo Alto, Washington DC]`

The user inputs: `[New York, Palo Alto]`

I want to compare the input to the collection and return "location already added." My code is as follows

```
var addevent = req.body.events;
    var addeventarr = addevent.split(',');
    Event.findOne({'location': eventloc }, 'events', function(err, event) {
        var eventcheck = event.events;
        console.log(eventcheck.indexOf(addeventarr));
```

I figured I could just do something like the following:

```
if(eventcheck.indexOf(addevent) != -1 || null){
console.log("already added");
}else{
console.log("added");
```

The indexOf however returns -1 not 0. If I enter only one "New York" I get the "already added" message, but if I try both I get the "added" message.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the aggregation framework for this and take advantage of [set operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/) like **[`$setIntersection`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIntersection/#exp._S_setIntersection)** which will return an array that contains the elements that appear in every input array.
So for your example if the user inputs the array `["New York", "Palo Alto"]`, applying the **[`$setIntersection`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIntersection/#exp._S_setIntersection)** on the `events` array with elements `["New York", "Palo Alto", "Washington DC"]`, this will return 
the set `["New York", "Palo Alto"]` since the array is common to both input and the collection's `events` array, thus this result will give you an indication of elements which are already added in the events array.

If the result brings in an empty array field then elements in the input array are not `members` of the `events` array so you can do the appropriate inference.

```
var addevent = req.body.events;
var addeventarr = addevent.split(',');
Event.aggregate([
    { "$match": { 'location': eventloc } },
    {
        "$project": {
            "commonEvents": { "$setIntersection": [ "$events", addeventarr ] }
        }
    }
], function(err, result) {
    console.log(result[0].commonEvents); // prints ["New York", "Palo Alto"]
});
```